# Does anybody have any information on Nimbus Look and Feel customization?

Tags: java, swing

Simply looking for some documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question. I found the information I needed in Jasper Potts presentation for JavaOne 2008, available on his blog at

http://www.jasperpotts.com/blog/2009/01/nimbus-the-new-face-of-swing-javaone-2008

Answer (score 1):

Nimbus is based on Synth, so you should look at customizing it from a Synth point of view, which is well documented.

Comment: I'm not sure about that. Most of it is built on vector graphics.

Comment: I'm sure that Nimbus is based on Synth, using vector graphics. If by your comment you mean you might lose the vector graphics in your customizations, if you treat it like Synth, that is true, you would have to use vector graphics for your customization.

Comment: @Yishai Up 1... thanks dor stearing me into right direction :)